# react-native deeplink only works one time

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I'm using deep linking in react-native in order to redirect the user on a specific youtube channel whenever he clicks on the button.

It's working well but when the user came back on the application using the back button, it's displaying a blank screen and I'm not able to redirect the user to the youtube channel anymore.

How can I make the deeplinking works every time ? Thanks !

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';

class ChaineYT extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading:false,
    isLinked: false
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    Linking.openURL('http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1UpcbyFVTZTDrvdjNmSzSg');
      this.setState({isLoading:true, isLinked:true});
        if(this.state.isLoading && this.state.isLinked){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Acceuil')
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default ChaineYT
```

How can I manage the youtube app in background ?

Comment: I think you mistyped `this.state.isLinked` in the line `if(this.state.isLoading && this.state.isLinking)`

Comment: No this is my mistake but I have `this.state.isLinked` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use AppState for it

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Linking, Platform, AppState } from 'react-native';

class ChaineYT extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading:false,
    isLinked: false,
    appState: AppState.currentState,

  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    Linking.openURL('http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1UpcbyFVTZTDrvdjNmSzSg');
      this.setState({isLoading:true, isLinked:true});

    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
       if(this.state.isLoading && this.state. isLinked){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Acceuil')
      }
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default ChaineYT
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! But I tried and it's the same result, when I click on my `Youtube Channel` button in my drawer it will launch the youtube app but if I come back it's still not re-render the youtube channel whenever I click on `Youtube Channel`

Answer (score -1):

Deeplink with react-navigation v5 in react-native is explained from scratch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8YaclRknYw)